# Spring boot 2 reactive web websocket conflict with datarest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-websocket, spring-webflux

I'm using spring boot 2 to create a project and use websocket using reactive web dependency. My application is worked correctly until I add datarest dependency. after I add datarest dependency application give

> ' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

is any way to resolve this conflict?.

*pom.xml*

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-file -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

*WebSocketConfiguration*

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfiguration {
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fileFlow(PublishSubscribeChannel channel, @Value("file://${HOME}/Desktop/in") File file) {
    FileInboundChannelAdapterSpec in = Files.inboundAdapter(file).autoCreateDirectory(true);

    return IntegrationFlows.from(
            in,
            p -> p.poller(pollerFactory -> {
                return pollerFactory.fixedRate(1000);
            })
    ).channel(channel).get();
}

@Bean
@Primary
public PublishSubscribeChannel incomingFilesChannel() {
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
}

@Bean
public WebSocketHandlerAdapter webSocketHandlerAdapter() {
    return new WebSocketHandlerAdapter();
}

@Bean
public WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler(PublishSubscribeChannel channel) {
    return session -> {
        Map<String, MessageHandler> connections = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        Flux<WebSocketMessage> publisher = Flux.create((Consumer<FluxSink<WebSocketMessage>>) fluxSink -> {
            connections.put(session.getId(), new ForwardingMessageHandler(session, fluxSink));
            channel.subscribe(connections.get(session.getId()));
        }).doFinally(signalType -> {
            channel.unsubscribe(connections.get(session.getId()));
            connections.remove(session.getId());
        });
        return session.send(publisher);
    };
}

@Bean
public HandlerMapping handlerMapping(WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler) {
    SimpleUrlHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
    handlerMapping.setOrder(10);
    handlerMapping.setUrlMap(Collections.singletonMap("/ws/files", webSocketHandler));
    return handlerMapping;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spring-boot-starter-data-rest` brings `spring-boot-starter-web` as a transitive dependency (so basically Spring MVC). This makes Spring Boot configure your application as a Spring MVC web application.

Spring Data REST does not currently support Spring WebFlux ([see this issue for more information on that](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-933)).

Your only choice is to remove the Spring Data REST dependency, as you can't have both Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux in the same Spring Boot application.